# PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(Context) difference between play store production vs alpha/beta

Tags: android, google-play

I need to detect if the app has been downloaded from the Play Store and if it was from production or alpha/beta channel.
Question n1: is it feasable?
 For what I've read so far it appears that the answer is no, however I've been looking at usages of `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(Context)` [here](https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.content.pm.PackageManager/getInstallerPackageName) and I see that 2 domains are usually looked for: `com.google` and `com.android` and they are both considered to be Google Play.
Question n2: what is the the difference between the two domains?